# Combo box if else query in ms access

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-access-2016

I created a field name 'tool_used' in which I specified some values and 'others' is one of its value. We can select multiple values from this box. I want to specify a condition that if the value of the field is others then a next field is visible that is 'other_tool'. I write a code for it but it gives a error 13 and when I debug it shows please specify a value in the field..
Please provide me the solution

My code is

```
Private sub tool_used_AfterUpdate() 
    If me.tool_used.value = "others" then 
        Me.other_tools.visible = true 
    Else 
        Me.other_tools.visible = False 
    End If 
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is multi select, you need to loop through the `ItemsSelected`.

```
Dim item As Variant

With YourListBox
    For Each item In .ItemsSelected
        Debug.Print .ItemData(item)
    Next item
End With
```

What happens if more than one item is selected, one of them is "Other"?

**Edit:**

Loop and set a flag if the "Other" option is selected. If not, the `other_tools` control will remain hidden.

```
Dim item As Variant, flag As Boolean

With YourListBox
    For Each item In .ItemsSelected
         If .ItemData(item) = "Other" Then flag = True: Exit For
    Next item
End With
    
other_tools.Visible = flag
```

Comment: Only if other is selected then only next field should visible   and if rest of the items are selected then the field remain hide

Comment: if we select multiple value except 'others'  the next field still hide..... but issue is when we select multiple value and other is also selected then the next field should be visible... the main thing goes around only 'others' value of this field.... if in any condition others is selected then the next field should visible...

Comment: I tried this code but now error 424 object required is pop up.

Comment: Can you please specify that YourListBox is a inbuilt function?

Comment: You need to replace `YourListBox` with your own control name.